# How to parse this JSON correctly? Says its property is undefined

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to parse this json string and it's not working. It's giving me a syntax error in chromes javascript console and firebug. Any help would be greatly appreciate! Thanks much!

```
"{ "SUCCESS" : false, "DATA" : '', "ERRORS" : [ "duplicate item" ]}"


Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

here's my code:

```
var json = objResponse;
//var obj = JSON.parse(json); //this doesn't work either
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);

alert(obj.SUCCESS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mismatch your quotes or your quote types, for example:

```
'{ "SUCCESS" : false, "DATA" : "", "ERRORS" : [ "duplicate item" ]}'
```

Will parse just find. An additional note, single quotes are not valid for a JSON string.

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or
>   false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be
>   nested.

Comment: You are correct that quotes should not be mismatched, but use this opportunity to point out that single quotes are illegal in JSON for the +1.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the single quotes (`'`) for `DATA`.

This helped me out:
http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Thanks for you help and I appreciate the awesome link. The answer below however is the one I used to solve my problem. But thanks again!

Comment: Interesting. I thought that `JSON.parse()` would have ignored validation errors and allowed single-quotes, but not so. So even though the code above is valid JavaScript (and would survive `eval`), it will fail JSON parsing. I only use double-quotes now, but I had no idea.